python collation sort "shift-trimmed"
How would I make this test pass?
names = [
    "cote",
    "coté",
    "côte",
    "côté",
    "ReasonE",
    "Reason1",
    "ReasonĔ",
    "Reason Super",
    "ReasonÅ",
    "ReasonA",
    "Reasona",
    "Reasone",
    "death",
    "deluge",
    "de luge",
    "disílva John",
    "diSilva John",
    "di Silva Fred",
    "diSilva Fred",
    "disílva Fred",
    "di Silva John",
]

loc = icu.Locale("und-u-ka-shifted-kb-true")
c = icu.Collator.createInstance(loc)

assert sorted(names, key=c.getSortKey) == [
    "cote",
    "côte",
    "coté",
    "côté",
    "death",
    "deluge",
    "de luge",
    "di Silva Fred",
    "diSilva Fred",
    "disílva Fred",
    "di Silva John",
    "diSilva John",
    "disílva John",
    "Reason1",
    "Reasona",
    "ReasonA",
    "ReasonÅ",
    "Reasone",
    "ReasonE",
    "ReasonĔ",
    "Reason Super",
]


Background:
I'm trying to replicate the sorting behavior from a postgres database.  Best I can figure is it's got custom rules for space/punctuation based on the 'shift-trimmed' option, along with 'backwards accent' (kb-true or [backwards 2])
ICU doesn't appear to support shift-trimmed and I'm not sure how else I could get these to sort "properly".
See collation settings and contextual sensitivity for more explanation.

What operating system are you using? The collation you are describing seems to be a French  shift-trimmed like sort like the sort used on glibc based systems before glibc change its collation towards shifted style collation.

I'm on Mac OS.  But, in theory I need the test to pass regardless of OS.  From what I can tell AWS postgres is using glibc from 2.26 (just prior to the major update)  whereas macOS doesn't use glibc.

But then macOS doesn't support 'backwards accent' either. ICU4C, ICU4J, ICU4X and modern implementations of glibc don't support 'shifted-trimmed'. MacOS, NetBSD, and Linux systems using musl libc are a no go for locale based collation. The only language I am aware of that supports 'shift-trimmed' is Perl, and considering the place Perl inhabits in postresql development ...

In theory the easiest cross platform approach would be to use shifted, rather than shift-trimmed. It sounds like you need compatibility with AWS postgres. The big change cam with 2.28, if memory serves. I suspect there are two approaches 1) modify the collation elements in allkeys_CLDR.txt (not the DUCET version) and use it with pyuca, or try to parse and modify the ICU sort keys. I'll have a look. the sort keys are byte arrays rather than collation elements, so I will see if I can backtrack.

pyuca can expose the collation elements, so it might be possible to write some functions to change or reorder the collation elements and then generate the sort keys. I'll explore that as well.
